# CGridView raises multiple on click events

Tags: binding, yii, cgridview

In my code, I'm using a `CGridView` and render it multiple times through ajax calls to list different sort of data to user. In one of its columns I have a `CButtonColumn` which is responsible for running a `javascript` function.it is my column code :

```
array(
            'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
            'template' => '{archive}',
            'buttons' => array(
                'archive' => array(
                    'url' => 'Controller::createUrl("/form/sendToArchive", array("flowId" => $data->id))',
                    'label' => Yii::t('app', 'Archive'),
                    'click' => 'function (){sendToArchive(this.href);return false;}',
                    'imageUrl' => '/themes/negin/images/archive.png',
                    'visible' => '$data->canBeArchived() ? true : false',
                ),
            ),
        ),
```

My problem is a common problem, but I still doesn't have any good solution for it. after each ajax call, CGridView got rendered and my `click` event binds multiple time to `CButtonColumn`. How can I prevent `CGridView` from this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

First Solution:

One of the best solution i ever found for such problem is that you must use a dynamic id for the button, So that when it loads on ajax response & bind to a javascript function, event always binds with new id so their will only one click.

You can use `time()`  with the button id to make it dynamic.

Or

The second solution to such problem would not be easy to make it practical but that is much better.

Always response your data in json format from ajax call, don't include any html or javascript code. 
Create your view on client side from the json response by using jQuery or any client side scripting language. JSON is lightweight & their is no html & js data So your ajax response would be much faster, It will also improve your application performace.